# Why is phaser.js displaying the entire sprite-sheet instead of a single frame of it?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am currently having a issue with loading Phaser.js sprite sheets. The main issue is that I have loaded a sprite sheet in via the "preload" method, and initialized the animations for the sprite in the "create" method, but multiple frames of the sprite sheet display on the screen rather than just one. (see [This Example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLClj.png).The sprite does show up on the screen, and its animations work properly, however the top and bottom of the other frames also show up above and below the intended sprite. My initial thought was the issues was perhaps in the preload method, but I double checked the documentation for sprite animations and I do not see what could be causing this particular issue. My next suspicions was perhaps the frame height/width parameters of the spritesheet, but I have not been able to solve the issue overall. I have also posted my Github link for [this project here](https://github.com/JokiestJoke/FleetAcademy), just in case you want to see the full code. Any idea what is causing the sprite sheet to load and animate this particular way? See below preload method:

```js
    class StartScene extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super({ key: 'StartScene' })
    }
    
    preload(){
        // preloads the main menu sprite
        this.load.spritesheet('startSprite',
        './assets/sprites/AdmiralMainMenuSpriteSheetv2.png',
        {
            frameWidth: 512,
            frameHeight: 384
        });

        //preloads main menu battleship
        this.load.spritesheet('battleshipMenu',
        './assets/sprites/battleshipSprite-Sheet1.png', 
        {
            frameWidth: 600, 
            frameheight: 300
        });
```

See below create method of the same class StartScene:

```js
    create(){
        //Sets the gamestate to active.
        gameStateMenu.active = true;

        //initiates the battleship sprite
        gameStateMenu.battleshipMenu = this.add.sprite(500, 350, 'battleshipMenu');

        //initiates the start sprite used for the Main Menu Screen. Syntax (X, Y, 'spriteKey')
        gameStateMenu.startSprite = this.add.sprite(210, 580, 'startSprite');
  

        // create all animations below
        //These animations will be manipulated in the create() method. 
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'battleshipMenuIdle',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers(
                'battleshipMenu',
                {
                    start: 0,
                    end: 8
                }),
                frameRate: 2,
                repeat: -1
        });

        // this creates the idle animation
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'idle',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers(
                'startSprite',
                {
                    start: 0,
                    end: 13
                }),
            frameRate: 5,
            repeat: -1
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you reduce this down into the smallest example that shows the problem?  This will give people trying to help you less to look through.

Comment: I think I have minimized it let me know if this is better

Comment: maybe you did not set the width/height correctly in preload function

Comment: I have cloned your repository but there's no './assets/sprites/AdmiralMainMenuSpriteSheetv2.png', or 
'./assets/sprites/battleshipSprite-Sheet1.png' assets in your repo, can't be tested.